# Design Pattern for Movie ticket booking system

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am working on movie ticket booking system. The system has to deal with multiple screens with different size and different showtime list. The ticket is basically dependent on cinemas, showtime and date, taxes. Admin will control it regularly. I am little bit of confused that which design pattern will good for this system, specially for the screens, showtime and seating allotment section. Please advice.

Comment: Please add more details about the requirements of the project - is it web application? is it desktop application? mobile maybe?

Comment: It is web, not desktop or mobile.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably too early to think about design patterns yet.

Make some classes and do some refactoring, then some design patterns may suggest themselves.

Comment: Please help on the problem, @Ray Tayek .....otherwise no need to answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a ticket booking system, you may want to start with following things.

- Authentication and Authorisation components (ACLs based) - AOP pattern
- Logging component - AOP, Abstract Factory Patterns
- Exception Handling - Exception Shielding pattern
- Data layer (DB and Cache system) - DAO, Strategy, Singleton, Factory patterns
- Service Layer - Facade, Proxy, IoC patterns
- Filters and Security -
- A web application typically needs a uniform way for presentation and processing - MVC pattern (REST-full request processing approach)
- Request processing - Front controller, Chain of responsibility (or Intercepting Filter in java world) pattern.

This may be a starting point for you I guess.

Comment: Thank you Arun, I am more concern about screens, showtime and seating relation. Any specific design pattern will be good for that?

Comment: I am not a UI person. Following links looks good. May be you have tried them.  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/10-ui-design-patterns-you-should-be-paying-attention-to/    and   http://ui-patterns.com/patterns

Comment: I am not talking about UI one. I am talking class related design pattern, you mentioned Abstract Factory for log-in component. What is for screens, showtime and seating one.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the UI is based on the requirements.
HTML & CSS for web app, Swing for Java desktop application and so on.

What should emphasized is how the UI will interact with your application.
Generally all implementation are based on [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architectural pattern.

- Model - represents the data & Business logic layers
- View - repesents the UI, every UI interaction are send to the controller
- Controller - represents the connection between the View & Model

The main purpose is to seperate between the UI implementation and the application logic.
Maybe this is the starting point you are looking for.

Comment: I am not talking about UI one. I am talking class related creational design pattern like Abstract Factory for log-in component. What is for screens, showtime and seating one.